How to Verify the Conjugate transpose

The operator $A$ is defined by the matrix
$$A_B:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 5 & -1 \\
2 & 7 & 3
\end{pmatrix} $$ in the basis $b_1=(1,2,1), b_2=(1,1,2), b_3=(1,1,0)$ of the space $R^3$. Find the conjugate transpose matrix in the same basis.

First, I found the transition matrix $P$ to the standard basis $$P= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
Then, I found the inverse matrix $$P^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0.5 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\
1.5 & -0.5 & -0.5
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Next, I found the representation of matrix A in the standard basis using the formula $A_E=P A_B P^{-1}$. After that, I transpose the obtained matrix to find the adjoint.
$$ A^{*}_E = \begin{pmatrix}
11 & 15 & 6 \\
-6 & -7 & -5 \\
4 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} $$
Then, I convert it back to the basis $B$ using the formula
$$ A^*_B=P^{-1} A_E P = \begin{pmatrix}
-72 & -61 & -39 \\
43.5 & 39 & 23 \\
75.5 & 60 & 42
\end{pmatrix} $$  However, when I want to check my result using the formula $ \langle A_B b_1, b_1 \rangle = \langle b_1, A^{*}_B b_1 \rangle $ I get different values.

Question: What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out. I would be grateful for any hints.

@geetha290krm The last formula is the property of conjugate transpose, why it has nothing to do with conjugate transpose?

Yes, the basis B is not orthonormal. Therefore, it is necessary to use the transition to the standard basis.

I'm wondering what other method there is to verify the correctness of finding the conjugate transpose?

Everything is ok. You need to show your checks.

Everything is ok. I've controlled all you calculations by Wolfram Alpha.
You can't easily use $\boxed{\langle A b_1, b_1 \rangle = \langle b_1, A^{*} b_1 \rangle}\color{red}*$ to check since $B \underline{\text{ is not orthonormal}}$.
$$A(b_1)=A_B\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}=1b_1+0b_2+2b_3$$
But it works : you find LHS of $\color{red}*=12$ and RHS of $ \color{red}* =12$ too.

Moreover, probably just a typo
$A^*_B=P^{-1} A_E^\color{red}* P = \begin{pmatrix}
-72 & -61 & -39 \\
43.5 & 39 & 23 \\
75.5 & 60 & 42
\end{pmatrix}$
